# Why if your local changes conflict with the upstream changes, you can stash your changes away, perform a pull, and then unstash?

Tags: git

From the manpage of git stash

> **Pulling into a dirty tree**
>
> When you are in the middle of something, you learn that there are
>   upstream changes that are possibly relevant to what you are doing.
>   When your local changes do not conflict with the changes in the
>   upstream, a simple  git pull  will let you move forward.
>
> However, there are cases in which your local changes do conflict with
>   the upstream changes, and  git pull  refuses to overwrite your
>   changes. In such a case, you can stash your changes away, perform a
>   pull, and then unstash, like this:
>
> ```
> $ git pull
>  ...
> file foobar not up to date, cannot merge.
> $ git stash
> $ git pull
> $ git stash pop
> ```

Why if "your local changes do conflict with the upstream changes, and  git pull  refuses to overwrite your changes", "you can stash your changes away, perform a pull, and then unstash"?

Does unstash also have conflict, and abort?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passage is talking a different kind of conflict.

If the changes in the upstream, that you're trying to pull into your current branch, includes files you have also changed locally you will be met with this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
<list of files>
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

In this case git simply refuses to pull, it has not verified that it would create any kind of "merge conflict" if it were to actually go through with the pull, instead it has been programmed to be "better safe than sorry". If, at any point, during the pull, git would encounter a merge conflict, then it would have to modify your locally modified but not yet committed files.

This, and the potential that you would be unable to clean up and fix this merge conflict, would probably lead to you losing changes. When you have actual commits involved you can simply abort the merge and retry but with uncommitted changes you simply don't have this option.

So git simply doesn't even try, instead you will have to first commit your changes, or stash them for safekeeping.

Now, all of this does not preclude you getting an *actual* merge conflict when you perform the commands it advises, but the word "conflict" in the text you post is a different kind of conflict.

Answer (score 1):

The unstash step is indeed likely to have a conflict.  But that does not *abort* the `pop`.  It only *aborts* the `drop` part of the pop, while *stopping* the `apply` part of the pop.

Any Git command that performs a *merge as a verb*, as I call this, can stop in the middle of the merge, leaving you with a mess that you must clean up manually.  The most obvious command that does this is `git merge` itself, which has two big parts: first, it does the merge-as-a-verb step, which either succeeds or stops.  Then, if that step succeeds, it commits the merge operation, making a *merge as a noun* as I like to call this part.  But if it did stop, it omits this part.

Having stopped in the middle, any *conflicted* merge leaves you to clean up the mess.  At this point, *all three input commits* are available in the index.  If you don't need those, Git's best-effort at combining the files is also available in your work-tree.  Use whatever tools you like to complete the merge, and then use `git add` to inform Git that your work-tree version is the correct result and that it should throw away the three inputs and just store your version into the index (aka staging area), ready to commit.

If the command you ran that resulted in this stopped merge was `git merge`, you can use `git merge --continue` or `git commit` to make the merge-as-a-noun.  If it was `git rebase`, you can use `git rebase --continue`, and so on.  For `git stash`, though, there's no `git stash pop --continue` (probably there should be): once you're *quite certain* that you've finished merging, you would use `git stash drop` to drop the stash.

I recommend always using (or almost always, once you're very used to all of this) `git stash apply` first, followed by a thorough check of the results, and then a separate `git stash drop` only once you're satisfied that Git got everything right.  Then the special case of "pop doesn't drop on merge conflict" never arises in the first place.